# Spring Actuator and @DataJpaTest cannot find CounterService bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-actuator

I have just setup Spring Actuator in my Spring boot project but now when I run my Jpa unit test spring complains

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.CounterService'
```

Because it cannot find the

```
@Resource
CounterService counterService;
```

This my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MyTestClass {
```

Comment: include the main class to @SpringBootTest(classes=MainApplication.java) or other classes to load for this test.

Comment: Yes this worked

Comment: `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` on one class does not make a lot of sense does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the main class to @SpringBootTest(classes=MainApplication.java) or other classes to load for this test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=MainApplication.java)
@DataJpaTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
public class MyTestClass {
```